# How to display JSON API feed into an HTML page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I would like to display the latest result from the following feed into an HTML page using JQuery. How can I do that?

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=15min&outputsize=full&apikey=demo

```js
$.getJSON('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=15min&outputsize=full&apikey=demo', function(data) { 
  var text = `Meta Data: ${data.Meta Data}`
  $(".mypanel").html(text);
});
```

```html
<div class="mypanel"></div>
```

Comment: where is your code.?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and see [ask]

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mypanel"></div>

    <script>
    $.getJSON('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=15min&outputsize=full&apikey=demo', function(data) {
        
        var text = `Meta Data: ${data.Meta Data}`
                  
                    
        
        $(".mypanel").html(text);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: 1. I can't see your code. 2. There is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response headers in that API, so you can't display directly with jQuery. 3. Update your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47610004/edit adding your code.

Comment: Tried following the following article but didn't work for my case.

http://zetcode.com/articles/javascriptjsonurl/

Comment: I pasted the code above, that previous article doesn't work for me. Not trying to read from a JSON file, but from a JSON API.

Comment: With http://time.jsontest.com/ you can because `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is present in the response headers. See: https://imgur.com/a/31xrX.

Comment: You need to update your QUESTION with the code you have. But anyway I answered the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the first of the Object keys AND you need to use `["..."]` for the Meta Data because it has a space:

```js
$.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=15min&outputsize=full&apikey=demo", function(data) {
  var $dl1 = $("#dl1"),
    $dl2 = $("#dl2");

  $.each(data["Meta Data"], function(key, value) {
    $dl1
      .append($('<dt>').html(key.replace(/ /g,"&nbsp;")))
      .append($('<dd>').text(value));
  });
  var first = Object.keys(data["Time Series (15min)"])[0];
  $.each(data["Time Series (15min)"][first], function(key, value) {
    if (key!="5. volume"){ 
      $dl2
        .append($('<dt>').text(key))
        .append($('<dd>').text(value));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ffa;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
dt {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
dd {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
  background: #ccc
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <dl id="dl1"></dl>
  <dl id="dl2"></dl>
```

Comment: Thank you, would it be possible to include the whole code starting with the HTML? Basically I want to display the latest values on an HTML page, but want to able to pick the parameters to show, i.e, Open & Close but not Volume. Many thanks.

Comment: See update. I assume you may run out of demo calls in which case you may want to use $.ajax and add an error handler. My code worked and then th call gave error eventually